# Encrypting attachments before sending mails

Tags: vba, email, encryption, outlook, attachment

I want to make sure that all mails I send with an attachment are encrypted. So is it possible to set this up in Outlook with `VBA`. Automatically encryption or something?

Alternatively maybe someone can help me with this:

So far I have made this code, which creates a pop-up (greater than 2 because I have 2 attachments in my signature):

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim lngAttach As Long
    Dim strPrompt As String
    strSubject = Item.Subject
    lngAttach = Item.Attachments.Count

    If lngAttach > 2 Then
        strPrompt = "Have you encrypted the file?"

        If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If    
    End If

End Sub
```

If I want it to open the attached file automatically if the answer is no, how do I make that?